# Finding elements present in only one of two lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, `heatmapNames` and `taxLabels`.

heatmapNames = ['dog', 'walrus', 'cat', 'pig', 'orca', 'moose', 'bear', 'fox', 'salamander']

taxLabels = ['cat', 'deer', 'mouse', 'rat', 'walrus', 'orca', 'fox']

I am trying to produce two new lists. One containing the elements in both lists called `sharedNames` and one containing elements found only in `heatmapNames` called `onlyHeatmapNames`.

Here is the code I have to do this:

```
sharedNames = []
onlyHeatmapNames =[]
onlyTaxLabels = []
for heatmapName in heatmapNames:
    for taxLabel in taxLabels:
        if heatmapName in taxLabel:
            sharedNames.append(heatmapName)
    if heatmapName not in onlyHeatmapNames:  
        onlyHeatmapNames.append(heatmapName)
```

While the `sharedNames` list is correct, some of the elements in `onlyHeatmapNames` are also found in `sharedNames`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would better do this:

```
sharedNames=[i for i in heatmapNames if i in taxLabels]
onlyHeatmapNames=[i for i in heatmapNames if i not in taxLabels]
onlyTaxLabels=[i for i in taxLabels if i not in heatmapNames]
```